# Are "char" and "small int" slower than "int"?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, processor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance of built-in types : char vs short vs int vs. float vs. double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double)

Hi. Assume, that you have **32-bit** processor. Are 8-bit `char` and 16-bit `short int` types slower than native 32-bit `int`?
What about using 64-bit `long long int`?

Are this datatypes supported by hardware by default, or they are all transformed into 32-bit data anyway, by using additional instructions?

In case, that I have to store a small amount of chars, isn't it faster to store them as ints?

Comment: If you're storing a *small amount of chars* why are you bothering with a potential nanosecond difference?

Comment: @Erik: A single variable could be used millions of times. Your argument doesn't follow.

Comment: @R.: And using wider types for chars could increase cache misses. Pointless optimization until the profiler proves otherwise.

Comment: @Erik: What are cache misses? Just in a few words, I don't need entire definition :) thanks

Comment: CPUs keep recently used memory location in "fast RAM"  This RAM is a cache to the much slower main memory.

Comment: @R.. Don'cha love how Erik changed the subject and addressed a strawman. And what's with people who can't spell your userid.

Comment: Optimization matters, and learning how to do things the fastest way possible is a good thing! . Please stop with the Premature Pessimization.

Comment: Stolen directly off the linked duplicate above:

Typically, CPUs are fastest at operating on integers of their native word size (with some caveats about 64-bit systems). 32 bit operations are often faster than 8- or 16- bit operations on modern CPUs, but this varies quite a bit between architectures. Also, remember that you can't consider the speed of a CPU in isolation; it's part of a complex system.

Comment: Even if operating on 16-bit numbers is 2x slower than operating on 32-bit numbers, you can fit twice as much data into the cache hierarchy when you represent it with 16-bit numbers instead of 32-bits. If that makes the difference between having all your data come from cache instead of taking frequent cache misses, then the faster memory access will trump the slower operation of the CPU.

Comment: Cache matters a lot more then CPU operations if you're iterating over sets of data so I'd wager that the smaller sizes would be faster - cooking up a benchmark now.

Comment: I can't post code as this is closed, please see my answer on the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On any modern, practical machine, `char`, `int`, and `long` will all be fast (probably equally fast). Whether `short` is fast or not varies somewhat between cpu architecture and even different cpu models within a single architecture.

With that said, there's really no good reason to use small types for single variables, regardless of their speed. Their semantics are confusing (due to default promotions to `int`) and they will not save you significant space (maybe not even any space). The only time I would ever use `char`, `short`, `int8_t`, `int16_t`, etc. is in arrays or structs that have to match a fixed binary layout of where you'll have so many of them (e.g. pixels or audio samples) that the size of each one actually matters.

Comment: Really? You'd use an int for a boolean instead of a signed char, for example?

Comment: Of course. Not only is it likely to generate smaller, faster code; it's also more idiomatic. All of the standard C functions that return truth values use `int` as their return type, and the value of all comparison/boolean operators in C has type `int`.

Comment: I'm too biased toward minimal designs to think that's right. lol. I'll try using this from now on.

Comment: @Spidey: I recommend against using `int` where you mean `bool` or `char`. Use the type you need.

Comment: Also note that signedness can matter. Arm for example has had instructions for fast "load and zero extend" of bytes for a long time but the support for fast "load and sign extend" of bytes was only added in a later version and has more restrictive addressing.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the operations in the instruction set as well as the compiler.