# c/c++ data type with fastest portable access by pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, primitive-types

I need to implement a large dynamic multi-dimensional bitmap (as in a map of bits) and speed and portability are both important. My first choise is `int`(doh!) but perhaps `long` or `long long` or maybe even `char` are better?

Comment: Portability across what platforms? Different word-lengths? Different instruction sets? Different compiler vendors? Different word endianness?

Comment: Way too vague to be a real question. Also is this C or C++ ?

Comment: You can expect `long long` and `char` to be slower. Go with int.

Comment: Portability across what platforms? **win/*nix(sunos,macos,linux)/exotic(embedded *nix)**  Different word-lengths? **yes**  Different instruction sets? **yes**  Different compiler vendors? **yes**  Different word endianness? **yes**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of built-in types : char vs short vs int vs. float vs. double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not bother that much, and the details depend upon the compiler, the optimization flags, the processor.

Don't forget that **premature optimization is evil**.

If you really care, make your code a template of the underlining integer type, or use a typedef to name it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this answer: [Performance of built-in types : char vs short vs int vs. float vs. double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double/5069643#5069643) it states that the type that is fastest depends on the processor architecture. So on a 32 bit architecture a 32 bit integer would be fastest, however on a 64 bit architecture a 64 bit integer. The answer to look for is the one by **Stephen Canon**.

Answer (score 0):

Every platform (hardware and compiler) is a bit different, so it's hard to say with any certainty that one data type is preferable over another.  That is, except to say that it is best to use a data-type of the same bit-size as the platform.  That is why I like to make a separate types.h file where I define my own data types for the current platform.  For example, I will do something like this for each data type:

```
#if defined(INT8)
#undef INT8
#endif
#define INT8 char
```