# Sql Order By - Varchar vs Integer

Tags: sql, complexity-theory, time-complexity, sql-order-by

Speaking with a friend of mine about DB structure, he says that for telephone number he use to create integer attributes and cast them directly into code that will extract data from DB (he add zero ahead number). Apart that method that could be questionable, I suggest him to use a varchar field.

He says that use a varchar is less efficient because:

- It take more memory for information storage (and this is true)
- It take more "time" for ordering the field

I'm pretty confused as I guess that rdbms, with all optimization, will do this sort in a `O(n log(n))` or something like regardless of data type. Mining the internet for information, unfortunately, turned out to be useless.

Could someone helps me understand if what I'm saying here has sense or not?

Thank you.

Comment: PoV performance: You friend is right, PoV functionality: IMHO No! Phone number changes, in Italy we have phone numbers start with 0 about land line, 3 about mobile, 8 free number and so on. If you use an integer you must apply a zero for some cases.

Comment: Sort telephone numbers??? Why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: @mavroprovato: yes you're totally right, but the question itself turns to other application fields :)

Comment: @JoeTaras: Ciao Joe, I'm italian too. Why do you agree with performance sentence? Could you argue?

Comment: @DonCallisto My point was that for this specific case, from a database design point of view, integer is a wrong choice. People want to use `+`, spaces and maybe parenthesis for phone numbers. If the data you wanted to store was indeed number, yes, you shouldn't consider a varchar. So first think of your data and then performance (for which as Hamlet Hakobyan points out, integer is better)

Comment: Hi, show here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double Argument is on C++ but the logic are the sames. Characters are conditioned by decoding and after interpreting the decoding them are translate in ASCII value. Integer jump these steps. To complete, you must consider time spent by processor to apply formatting to your number to show properly.

Comment: @JoeTaras: nice, I'll take a read. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS use indexes to optimize ordering(sorting). Indexes stored as B-tree in the storages and is more large as the indexed field(s) is. Thus the disk IO operations increases because the data is large. In another hands, the `O(n log(n))` is different for different type of data. The semantic of comparing string and numeric(integer) are different and comparison of strings are more complicated than integers.

Comment: Could you point me to some documentatio about this O(n log(n)) is different for different type of data? Isn't it stackable for any tipe of data? I mean, once you've created a b-tree, you should traverse it in same time.. What I'm missing?

Comment: `you should traverse it in same time.. ` yes, of course, the same time for the same tree, I mean if you have the trees of different type then traversing through will be different in case that to make decision to which node you must choose you will spend different time (comparison of strings are more complicated than integers).