# Finding Unexercised Bits of Allocated Data

Tags: c++, c, optimization, memory-management, d

Is there a tool out there to check for unexercised bits in allocated data in C/C++?

We could make use of such tool a when we're trying to reduce the memory consumption in the DMD D compiler written in C++. For details see [this post](http://forum.dlang.org/thread/rvsahztwahdkwumcbjoa@forum.dlang.org).

**Update**: I guess [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) is a good contender, right?

Comment: What are "unexercised bits"?

Comment: Bits that are not used. For instance a C `enum` defaults to 32 bits but almost never are all those bits used to store information. If you an enum with `n` alternatives `ceil(log2(n))` bits are used.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the conversation, I think the first thing you should do is use massif like you suggested. 
Then if you see that some particular type is allocated a lot you can look into that.

Spontaneously though, unexercised bits doesn't strike me as a critical memory hog in a compiler, there should be bigger things in AST construction and above all optimization (ipo).

Also, if you find some type that actually benefits size-wise by switching to a type with smaller footprint, make sure to benchmark for performance. Benchmarking is important since if one specific 4/8 byte type shows up enough to make a difference, then it may well matter that cpus typically are slower when doing computations on types that are not their native word size,

see: [Performance of built-in types : char vs short vs int vs. float vs. double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double)