# The Code doesn't print the expected output, why?

Tags: c, struct, io, stdin

The following code doesn't behave as expected ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct dest
{
    char filename[20], keyword[20];
    bool opened;
    FILE * file;
};


void display_data(const struct dest p) {
    printf("Keyword: %s, Filename: %s, Used: %s\n", p.keyword, p.filename, p.opened ? "Yes" : "No");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    // declaring variables
    float lon, lat;
    char info[80];
    FILE *reader;

    // checking required arguments
    if ((argc+1) % 2 || argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file_to_read file_for_unknown type file type file ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }

    // opening the reader
    if (!(reader = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File can't be accessed: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    // creating important globals
    const short pairs = (argc-3)/2;
    struct dest data[pairs];

    struct dest other;
    strcpy(other.filename, argv[2]);
    other.opened = false;

    // gathering data
    short times = 4;
    for(short i = 4; i < argc; i += 2) {
        data[i-times].opened = false;
        strcpy(data[i-times].keyword, argv[i-1]);
        strcpy(data[i-times].filename, argv[i]);
        times += 1;
    }

    // finally, scanning the file ..
    struct dest *use_f; // pointer for the wanted destination ..
    bool known;
    while (fscanf(reader, "%f,%f,%79[^\n]", &lat, &lon, info)) {

        // deciding which file to use ..
        known = false;
        for(short i=0; i < pairs; ++i) {
            if (strstr(info, data[i].keyword)) {
                known = true;
                use_f = &data[i];
            }
        }

        if (!(known)) {
            use_f = &other;
        }

        // checking the file ..
        if (!((*use_f).opened)) {
            (*use_f).file = fopen((*use_f).filename, "w");
            (*use_f).opened = true;
        }

        // writing to the file ..
        fprintf((*use_f).file, "%f,%f,%s\n", lat, lon, info);
    }

    // closing all data streams, and informing user ..
    for (short i=0; i < pairs; ++i) {
        display_data(data[i]);
        if (data[i].opened) {
            fclose(data[i].file);
            data[i].opened = false;
        }
    }

    fclose(reader);
    fclose(other.file);

    return 0;
}
```

The command used to run it is this ..

> ./categorize spooky.csv other.csv UFO UFOS.csv # I get no output at all

It seems that the while loop doesn't actually end, which is mysterious, because the file (spooky.csv) is only 11 lines !

> 30.685163,-68.137207,Type=Yeti
>   28.304380,-74.575195,Type=UFO
>   29.132971,-71.136475,Type=Ship
>   28.343065,-62.753906,Type=Elvis
>   27.868217,-68.005371,Type=Goatsucker
>   30.496017,-73.333740,Type=Disappearance
>   26.224447,-71.477051,Type=UFO
>   29.401320,-66.027832,Type=Ship
>   37.879536,-69.477539,Type=Elvis
>   22.705256,-68.192139,Type=Elvis
>   27.166695,-87.484131,Type=Elvis

It just keeps writing to other.file, yet I don't know why ..
The program simply doesn't end, can anybody explain things to me ?

Comment: @redFIVE like what ? I don't know any good c debuggers ..

Comment: @AmrAyman Try checking the return value of `fscanf` and printing out the values it reads.

Comment: Just out curiosity, why are you using `short` instead of `int`?

Comment: @Jack For memory efficiency ..

Comment: Why so many down votes ? What's wrong with the question o.O ?

Comment: @AmrAyman: Actually, there's no such a warranty. Maybe the processor may work fastest using its natural data type size, an int.

Comment: @Jack Aren't shorts supposed to get only 2 bytes while ints take 4, and after all, I know the number of arguments won't exceed 32,767 or 65,535 (if unsigned), so why consume more memory when I'm certain I won't need it all .. Even if the processor is used to int, what's the reason to not using shorts if some processors just allocate the same memory for both ints and shorts ..

Comment: Yes, it's on 32-bit machine. It may use less memory but executation time is a bit different from memory usage. A program can use more to get more performance(e.g, memorization, cache etc). Also, check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double

Comment: It would a example of premature optimization...

Comment: So the big picture is .. that: larger_memory_usage == faster execution, and less_memory_usage == memory conservation but not so fast execution .. I think that makes sense ..

Comment: @halfer thanks for your concern .. Yes, I have done installed both of them
Do you mean CGI Scripts ? By the way, I've already collected a personal ebook library and started with reading some books and I'm willing to continue till I create a website, unfortunately, all docs or books I've read only suggest I pay for a hosting service, and I kept on wondering why should I pay for a hosting server while I can install apache on my machine, learn through the progress and deploy the website at the end ..

Comment: However, all the webpages I created didn't get past through localhost .. Which is really unpleasing and not very paying off for me as I wished, I kept on researching for about four months by now and I don't know if web development is really worth all that trouble, and I'm seriously thinking about focusing completely on desktop development .. I'm even trying to learn node at the moment, just to know that the month it took me to learn javascript (the first language I learnt) wasn't in vein .. :/

Comment: Web development is definitely worth the trouble! "All the webpages I created didn't get past through localhost" - what do you mean?

Comment: "Do you mean CGI Scripts" - well, PHP can use a CGI interface, but we don't really think in those terms now. PHP scripts are just written in PHP.

Comment: "while I can install apache on my machine", yes - just installed MAMP/WAMP etc as an all-in-one package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57535/discussion-between-amr-ayman-and-halfer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `fscanf()` manpage: "The value EOF is returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion (such as an end-of-file) occurs."

Here's a hint... EOF isn't equal to 0.  Your while-loop never terminates.