# Objective C float vs int, CGPoint vs custom int based struct performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

Based on the arguments in this post: [Performance of Built-in types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double), can I conclude that my custom implementation of a int based point structure is faster or more efficient than the float-based CGPoint? I have reviewed many posts concerning the type performance differences but have not found one that includes scenarios further wrapped by a structure.
Thanks.

```
// Coord 
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Coord;

CG_INLINE Coord CoordMake(int x, int y){
    Coord coord; coord.x = x; coord.y = y; return coord;
}

CG_INLINE bool CoordEqualToCoord(Coord coord, Coord anotherCoord) {
    return coord.x == anotherCoord.x && coord.y == anotherCoord.y;
}

CG_INLINE CGPoint CGPointForCoord(Coord coord) {
    return CGPointMake(coord.x, coord.y);
}
```

EDIT: I have done purely arithmetical tests and the results are really negligible until millions of iterations, which my application will not come close to doing. I will continue to use the Coord `typedef` but will remove the struct for a few of the reasons @meaning-matters suggests. For the record the tests did show that the int based structure was about 30% faster, but 30% of 0.0001 seconds is not really something anyone should care about.  I am still interested in the points and counter-points on which implementation is better.

Comment: You can get academic answers all day long, but I bet a simple performance test would trump all of them.

Comment: I assume your'e doing this for "grins", not production code?

Comment: I came to stack for the academic argument to go along with the scientific evidence.  Yes, I do plan on using this with my own project, not just for grins.  Is my implementation faulty?

Comment: [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth): "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." But what does he know.

Comment: Faster in what way? Which operations? Accessing members? There is not much more a `struct` can do.

Comment: As soon as you start doing graphics, the optimization of a few CGPoint calculations is, er, pointless.

Comment: "can I conclude that my custom implementation of a int based point structure is faster than the float-based CGPoint?" - no, not like that.

Comment: Not being used for graphics.

Comment: If not for graphics, what is the application?

Comment: Here is the deal: Write the code in in the most clear way possible. Less is more. Test the app, if it is deemed to slow then measure and find out exactly what is slow, attack that until it is faster. Rise and repeat. Now, it is possible that `float` based `CGPoint` is the problem, then fix that and the only way to know if the fix is correct is measurement. Ex: We were doing a unix port that was dog slow. I wrote a profiler and we found that 90% of the cpu time was in `memcpy()`! With that information `memcpy()` time was reduced to < 3%. We never expected that.

Comment: How can one struct be faster than another? Obviously, a struct's performance depends on the kind of operations that are performed on the struct. In your case the result heavily depends on the number of conversions needed to interface to Cocoa APIs, as int to float conversion is slow.

Comment: @meaning-matters - "If not for graphics, what is the application", A 2D coordinate system used for procedurally generated maps.  If someone could explain the down vote that would be appreciated.  This question has obviously sparked debate on both sides of the fence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing with it. For ordinary arithmetic, throughput can be similar. Integer latency is usually a bit less. On some processors, the latency to L1 is better for GPRs than FPR. So, for many tests, the results will come out the same or give a small edge for integer computation. The balance will flip the other way for double vs int64_t computation on 32-bit machines. (If you are writing CPU vector code and can get away with 16-bit computation then it would be much faster to use integer.)

However, in the case of calculating coordinates/addresses for purposes of loading or storing data into/from a register, integer is clearly better on a CPU. The reason is that the load or store instruction can take an integer operand as an index into an array, but not a floating point one.  To use floating point coordinates, you at minimum have to convert to integer first, then load or store, so it should be always slower.  Typically, there will also have to be some rounding mode set as well (e.g. a floor() operation) and maybe some non-trivial operation to account for edging modes, such as a CL_ADDRESS_REPEAT addressing mode. Contrast that to a simple AND operation, which may be all that is necessary to achieve the same thing on integer and it should be clear that integer is a much cheaper format.

On GPUs, which emphasize floating-point computation a bit more and may not invest much in integer computation (even though it is easier), the story is quite different. There you can expect texture unit hardware to use the floating point value directly to find the required data. The floating point arithmetic to find the right coordinate is built in to the hardware and therefore "free" (if we ignore energy consumption considerations) and graphics APIs like GL or CL are built around it.

Generally speaking, though ubiquitous in graphics APIs, floating-point itself is a numerically inferior choice for a coordinate system for sampled data.  It lumps too much precision in one corner of the image and may cause quantization errors / inconsistencies at the far corners of the image, leading to reduced precision for linear sampling and unexpected rounding effects.  For large enough images, some pixels in the image may become unaddressable by the coordinate system, because no floating-point number exists which references that position. It is probably the case that the default rounding mode, round to nearest ties to even is undesirable for coordinate systems because linear filtering will often place the coordinate half way between two integer values, resulting in a round up for even pixels and round down for odd. This causes pixel duplication rather than the expected result in the worst case where they are all hell ways cases and the stride is 1. It is nice in that it is somewhat easier to use.

A fixed-point coordinate system allows for consistent coordinate precision and rounding across the entire surface and will avoid these problems. Modulo overflow feeds nicely into some common edging modes. Precision is predictable.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed by a quick search 32-bit `int` and `float` operations seem equally fast on ARM processors (and take 1 CPU cycle each). Please look for yourself and do a simple test as Zev Eisenberg correctly suggests.

Then it's not a good idea to start writing your own `CGPoint` stuff using `int`s for the following reasons (to name a few):

- Incorrect results: Rounding or truncating coordinates to integers will give all kinds of weird/horrible/side effects.
- Incompatibility with the multitude of iOS libraries.
- A big waste of time.
- Not faster.
- Creating a messy code base (Knuth is right as Zaph brings in).

As always when trying to optimise: Take a step back and investigate if your current method/algorithm is the best choice (for possibly different scenario's in your application). This is the way to commonly massive improvement of hundreds of percents.

Comment: Confusing the the next developer.

Comment: There is a latency issue with floating point instructions so they may be slower depending on the code. That is once the pipe is primed one floating point instructions can be retired per cycle but it may take several cycles to prime the pipe. But I do not shy away from floating point.

Comment: @Zaph Pipeline optimisation will help against this. But indeed a valid point, and correct you say 'may be slower'.

Comment: I have done purely arithmetical tests and the results are really negligible until millions of iterations, which my application will not come close to doing.  I will continue to use the Coord typedef but will remove the struct for a few of the reasons @meaning-matters suggests.  For the record the tests did show that the int based structure was about 30% faster, but 30% of 0.0001 seconds is not really something anyone should care about.

Comment: @meaning-matters I will. I was hoping it being unanswered would cause more people to vote up the question... so its at least not in the negative.