# Why use the 'int' data type instead of the 'float' data type?

Tags: c++

Lately I've been learning some C++ but I've run into a conundrum:

As we know, the 'int' data type is used to hold integers and whole numbers, while the 'float' data type is used to define variables holding real and fractional numbers. However, I do find that I can place an integer into a variable of the 'float' data type just as easily, removing the need to use the 'int' type?

If that is the case, why would I continue using the 'int' data type over 'float'? It would be more convenient to use the latter... would it be considered poor form?

Comment: There are plenty of places where floating point makes no sense. What's the 3.1415926-th element in an array? Also, integer arithmetic are usually faster than floating point.

Comment: "I can place an integer into a variable of the 'float' data type" - but not all integer values. Try converting `int(1000000001)` to `float` and back to `int`, and see what you get.

Comment: I can place an `int` into a `bool`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is considered to be slower than int in arithmetic computations.
You may not use floats in comparisons because of their precession. ([read more here](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm))

This is a good post as well :

[Float vs. integer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069643/2736559)

> Historically, floating-point could be much slower than integer
>   arithmetic. On modern computers, this is no longer really the case (it
>   is somewhat slower on some platforms, but unless you write perfect
>   code and optimize for every cycle, the difference will be swamped by
>   the other inefficiencies in your code).
>
> On somewhat limited processors, like those in high-end cell phones,
>   floating-point may be somewhat slower than integer, but it's generally
>   within an order of magnitude (or better), so long as there is hardware
>   floating-point available. It's worth noting that this gap is closing
>   pretty rapidly as cell phones are called on to run more and more
>   general computing workloads.
>
> On very limited processors (cheap cell phones and your toaster), there
>   is generally no floating-point hardware, so floating-point operations
>   need to be emulated in software. This is slow -- a couple orders of
>   magnitude slower than integer arithmetic.
>
> As I said though, people are expecting their phones and other devices
>   to behave more and more like "real computers", and hardware designers
>   are rapidly beefing up FPUs to meet that demand. Unless you're chasing
>   every last cycle, or you're writing code for very limited CPUs that
>   have little or no floating-point support, the performance distinction
>   doesn't matter to you.

I would suggest you to read the whole post to get a clear view of their distinctions.

Comment: "Float takes more space than int does". `static_assert(sizeof(float) > sizeof(int), "Not on my system");`

Comment: @TristanBrindle:Thanks, i corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Some reasons:

- `int` is almost universally more efficient
- `int` allows bit-wise operations
- `int` is the return type for `main()`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the efficiency issue mentioned in other answer, you should also aware of the fact that using float is actually less intuitive than int.

For a comparison, you should almost never do something like

```
if (aFloat == anotherFloat) { ...
```

You need to understand that not all decimal values can be exactly represented by a floating number.