# Using chars as digits,

Tags: java, char

I am writing a simulation that will use a lot of memory and needs to be fast. Instead of using ints I am using chars (8 bits not 32). I need to operate on them as if these chars were ints.

To achieve that I have done something like

```
char a = 1; 
char b = 2; 
System.out.println(a*1 + b*1); //it give me 3 in console so it has int-like behavior;
```

I don't know what's going on "under the mask" when I multiply char with an integer. Is this the fastest way to do it?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Java `char` is [16 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), not 8.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise it's not worth using char instead of int, because all modern hardware architectures are optimized for 32- or 64-bit wide memory and register access.

Only reason to use char would be if you want to reduce memory footprint, i.e. if you work with large amount of data.

Additional info: [Performance of built-in types : char vs short vs int vs. float vs. double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double)

Comment: yup i am going to work with large amount of data, sth like 10 000 ints and more.

But speed is also importand, and thats why i dont want to cast char on int. I think i will have to work out some kind of char-like algebra and then at the very end interprete the result as it were int.

Comment: If you want to squeeze out every last bit of performance I would consider stepping away from Java and rather go for plain C. There are ways to parallelize byte-wise-computations, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD If performance is not that critical just accept the casts, cause there is no way you can avoid them if you do common arithmetic operations in Java. char computations aren't any faster than int computations, because chars are implicitly converted to int anyways.

Answer (score 0):

A char is simply a number (not a 32bit int but a number) which is normally represented ascii-encoded. By multiply it with an integer the compiler does an implicit cast from char to int that's why you get printed 3 on the console instead of the ascii representative.

Comment: then is there any kind of char-like algebra? With compiler understand totaly as a operations on chars and do not perform any casting it to ints ?

Comment: I don't know if 'a'-'c' or such are still chars but with a cast to char it works without doubt
e.g. (char)('a'-'c')

Answer (score 0):

You should use ints. the size of the character will not affect the fetch speed of the data, nor the processing time unless it is composed of multiple computer words, which is unlikely. There is no reason to do this. Moreover, chars are stored as integers and are therefore the same size. an alternative would be to use small ints but again this is not helpful for what you want.

Also, I notice your code has 'System.Out.Println' which means you are using java. There are several implications of this, the first is that no, you are not going to be going fast or using very little memory. Period, it will not happen. There is a large amount of overhead involved in running the JVM, JIT, garbage collector and other parts of the Java platform. If efficiency is a relavent factor you are starting off wrong. The second implication is that your choice of datatypes will have no impact on processing time because they will be identical to the physical hardware. Only the Virtual machine will distinguish between them, and in the case of primitives, there is no difference anyways.