# Choosing a data type based on size

Tags: c++

I wanted to know when you all(experienced programmers) program in C++, how do you choose primitive data types? For instance, if you have a for loop that you know iterates 4 times, do you use unsigned short int or int8_t? Why? or why not? Is it all about optimizing memory?

There are so many types of int with different sizes, I figured there must be a reason.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double

Comment: I think this is a useful question, but be aware that answers will contain opinions which you may find surprisingly controversial.  Google's C++ Style Guide's advice is found here:  https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the native word size when specialized sizes are not required. For example, I use `unsigned int` for all counting loops.

When accessing hardware, I use the specific size integers, such as `uint16_t` or `uint8_t`.

With modern desktop computers, which have a lot of memory and speed, there is no need for premature optimizations like worrying about variable sizes.

In embedded systems, especially where memory is constrained, variable sizes may make a difference.

The best practice is to get the program working correctly, then apply optimizations as required.  A very small buggy program is not as useful as a large correctly and robust program.  Same for speed.

### Rationale

Processors are really efficient when using their native word size.  Word sizes vary depending on the processor.  Some processors are 8-bit word sizes, some 16, others 32-bit (and yes, there are sizes between and greater).

Data that is not the size of the processor's word (register), may cause additional effort by the processor.  For example, a processor that has a 16-bit word size would need to make two memory fetches to build a 32-bit quantity.  A 32-bit processor will fetch 32 bits for a 16-bit quantity than may have to shift bits or mask bits to get the 16-bit quantity into the correct position in the processor's register.

Hardware registers come in different sizes.  When there is a hardware register that is 8-bits wide, one doesn't want to write 32-bits to the register, which is why there is an 8-bit wide data type versus a 32-bit data type.

Comment: Good explanation. So it turns out that `static_cast`-ing primitive types to each other imposes a little runtime overhead, actually.

Comment: If you use `unsigned int` for all counting loops, it will eventually sneak into loop body arithmetic involving the loop counter, where the `unsigned` will "infect" the other operands, causing surprising conversions. It's okay if you're only, for instance, indexing into arrays.  Or stepping over the domain of some function which takes its input as an unsigned int anyway.

Comment: @kaz: With signed variables, you're allowing the index to be negative.  So for iterating, you are allowing a negative index, which in most cases is wrong.  I usually don't use the index variable in math operations.  Also, the signed integer has less positive values than the unsigned version.

Comment: No. Simply declaring something `int` doesn't make it negative; you actually have to execute some code that puts a negative value there. The problem is arguably in that code.  Just like if we have a value that should be a prime integer, and we put something composite in there. We could catch that with a `prime_t` type which does run-time (or even compile time) primality testing. But that analogy is flawed, because the `unsigned` type doesn't actually do domain error checking; it silently converts what would be an incorrect negative to some incorrect, large, positive and the show goes on.

Comment: `unsigned` means that if  we have  `a + b < c`, we cannot do simple algebra and move something across the inequality sign, like `a < c - b`, even if all three variables are small values of several bits near zero. `c - b` could wrap and produce some `0xFFFFFFE7` value or whatever. Basically `unsigned` is an "anti-negative-value defense system" for algebra flunkies.

Comment: Pick the datatype that sufficiently fits the problem space because poor design and maintainability is a far, far bigger and prevalent problem. Applying structured and OO principles from that `for loop` on up means "which primitive?" becomes irrelevant in the "Big O" sense. A rich, problem domain oriented data API definitely influences high level design. It's like the invisible guiding hand of OO.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, if there is no particular reason OTHERWISE, I use `int` for all iterative loops with a loop counter. Of course, when iterating over a container, I use the new style loops:

```
std::string str = "Hello, World!";
for(auto c: str)
    std::cout << c;
```

(A rather silly way to print "Hello, world!")

The reason for using `int` is that it's meant to be the "best" size of an integer for speed on that particular architecture. It may not be slower to use `int8_t` or some other type, but it's also not guaranteed that the compiler doesn't have to perform extra steps to "widen" the `int8_t` when making comparisons, such that:

```
 for(int8_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   ...
```

essentially becomes:

```
 for(int8_t i = 0; (int)i < 4; i++)
  ...
```

and thus, the code is larger and slower.

In everything but really tiny processors [or very large loops where the counter itself isn't used much], the loop variable `i` will be in a register anyway, and 99% of the time, you can't usefully store more than one thing in a register [without penalty, even if for example x86 allows `al` and `ah` as two 8-bit registers formed from the 64-bit `rax`, it IS one register, and the processor will have to deal with "partial register updates" which complicates for the processor, and on many variants of x86 processors will slow the code down, it's unlikely that the compiler indeed uses the other parts of the register for anything useful]

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to comparison (as in case with `while(i < 4)`), the best option is when the values being compared have the same type. [Integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) `4` has type of `int`, so `i` should be of the same type (or larger) to avoid overflow. It is also important that valuess should have the same signedness. If for some reason they have different signedness, you should manually cast them to the appropriate type, but make sure that the cast is safe. One typical example:

```
size_t max = 4096;
ssize_t n = read(fd, buf, max);
if(n < 0) {
    handle_error(errno);
    return;
}
assert(n >= 0); // Now we are sure we can cast away signedness safely
if((size_t)n < max) {
    // ...
}
```

Fixed-size integer types (like `uint8_t`, `uint32_t` etc.) should be used only when the size is critical for a certain problem. For example, when serializing integers into file that could be read on another computer.

I usually don't bother about performance when selecting primitive types as robustness is more important to me.