# Can you get smaller integer in any low level language independent of architecture?

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

An integer could be 8 bytes, which is 2^64. A lot of values.

Let say I wanted to write a small program that would store value like this in a file:

`3 1 5 6 2 8 9 0 1 2 ....`

at no point my value is going to be higher that 9. So I only need 10 combinations, 
that I can get by data type that takes 2^4 (16 combinations) only. Not 2^64.

won't it be more efficient.. how can I accomplish that. Does C++ has native single digit type.

Comment: have you heard of BCD (binary coded decimal?)

Comment: I second @RichardHodges see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

Comment: You can use `short`, or if you prefer a fixed size type you can use something from [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

Comment: @RichardHodges no, i hardly do programming at such low level, i used to be more familiar but that was years ago.

Comment: Do note that unless it really is a performance concern by default you should just an `int`.  It takes up more space but most/all implementations work very efficiently with `int`s.

Comment: _"An integer could be 8 bytes"_ Yes, but in practice it's only 4 bytes on most common architectures in use today. _"won't it be more efficient."_ What do you mean by more efficient? It will take up less space, but it might take a lot more processing time to work with.

Comment: @JonathanWakely why would it be more computationally expensive? Although i was aiming for smaller storage space.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer A good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double

Comment: @MuhammadUmer because processors are designed to work with their native word, and that is usually the type that `int` corresponds to. Working with smaller types might involve extending the value to a wider type, performing arithmetic, then masking off the high bits. That involves more CPU instructions than simply performing the arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make such a type, but you probably don't want to.

I would suggest you use `unsigned char` or `signed char`, which are both single-byte types.  (You may consider using the type aliases `std::uint8_t` and `std::int8_t`, which better express your intent to store 8-bit numbers.)

It is possible to create a class with a single-byte numeric member that can store two separate digits, but you will lose performance since operations will have to extract the digit you care about, possibly shift it, and then the reverse operation when assigning to it.  That is to say, statements like:

```
numbers[1] = v;
```

Would wind up being implemented something like:

```
combined_numbers[0] = (combined_numbers[0] & 0x0f) | (v << 4);
```