# Should I use unions to accelerate execution time?

Tags: c, unions

I am using an 8x8 matrix, whose values can be between -6 and +6.

Although it could be stored in a char matrix, I think that using int types should be faster because it is not necessary to sign extend the values when loading into registers. I have also read that it can cause cache problems, but I don't think it should happen.

The isse is that as I copy many times this matrix, I have thought that it could be worthy to create an union similar to:

```
union my_union{
char c[8];
int64_t i;
};
```

in order to make only 8 copies instead of 64. Is it not recommended for any reason?

EDIT:

The architecture used is x86_64. The compiler is GCC 5.4 with -O3 flag activated.

Comment: As always with optimization questions: Did you actually spot a bottleneck in your program that makes it **worth** optimizing it?

Comment: As for your idea, just use `memcpy()` instead.

Comment: so many assumptions...

Comment: I would worry (much) more about total size, than sigh-extension. I suck at x86, but from a [quick look at Agner](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) it seems `movsx` takes 1 cycle on modern x86 cores. Caches are limited though, so cutting down the size of a core datastructure by a factor of 4 (or 8 if `sizeof (int)` is 8) sounds like a major win.

Comment: How many such matrices do you use? Is the total size exceeds CPU cache size?

Comment: Memcpy seams indeed to be a good idea. I didn't care about size because the program is trying to use the whole CPU while it doesn´t use 1% of the RAM and I read that int is faster here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double

Comment: @DaBler I declare up to 20 matrices, so it is not a big size. The issue is that they are copied, modified and read billions of times.

Comment: This is completely pointless to speculate about without a specific system in mind. Please update your question and state: target system/CPU, compiler used, compiler options used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding a `union` type-punning an 8 elements `char` to `int64_t`:

> Is it not recommended for any reason?

It wouldn't be well-defined C code. Reading a different member of a `union` than the member last written to is undefined behavior with very rare exceptions.* Also, even ignoring that, while `int64_t` has some strong guarantees (like 64 bits, no padding, ...), a `char` could have more than 8 bits, leaving your copy based on the `int64_t` buggy / missing some bits.

---

As already commented, the first thing to try for well-performing copies of objects is the standard library function `memcpy()`. It is expected to perform best in most situations.

---

*) a notable exception is a `union` containing two `struct`s that share a common initial sequence. Given the `union` declaration is visible, inspecting the "other" member is allowed in that case.

Comment: You are right about char. However, if the type were changed into int8_t then the size would be ensured. Regarding to the optimality, it seems to be that memcpy is better than creating an union, but if somebody actually wanted to create it and s/he used the larger type only for copying the information, would it be a reason to avoid that?

Comment: I think I stated the main reason: Doing so isn't valid C.

Comment: If we disregard various signedness and endianess issues, then type punning from a 8 byte char array to int64_t is well-defined, if they are part of the same union. Accessing the data through a union type is a valid exception from the strict aliasing rule. C allows this, unlike C++. 6.5.2.3/3 and 6.5/7.

Comment: Anyway this doesn't answer the question - it can't be answered in its current form.

Comment: @Lundin that's not true. A union can only contain one of its members (6.7.2.1 p16), the type of a different member is not in the list given in 6.5 p7 and the only explicit exception is given in 6.5.2.3 p6. So, accessing the "wrong" member results in a reinterpretation according to 6.5.2.3 p3 footnote 95 and this already includes the warning "*This might be a trap representation.*". Yes, it doesn't violate "strict aliasing" as long as the union declaration is visible, but it's not well-defined *unless* you can make further assumptions.

Comment: The point is that the variable is not modified as an array of int8_t and read as an int64_t nor the opposite. They are always used as int8_t and int64_t mode is only used to copy the whole array of int8_t so I don't see where does the undefined behaviour appear.

Comment: @Zeropoint it's a special case with these two types that you *know* (**if** they exist in the first place) that the sizes match **and** there are no trap representations. Your first version in your question already didn't guarantee that. In the general case, type punning is **not** well defined. There's just no need to start writing potentially bad code ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen `intN_t` types are defined to not have padding, and are always two’s complement representation. I don't think there's space for trap representations.

Comment: @user694733 see comment above. `intN_t` can't have any, indeed. If you either have specific knowledge about the implementation or only use types that have special guarantees in the standard, you can implement "safe" type-punning. I just don't see any reason to start such dangerous stuff (and I take the original suggestion by OP being indeed unsafe as example for my argument). `memcpy()` should do what is needed. (Also, problems with strict aliasing may be around the corner if you refactor your code and start just passing pointers to the union members)