# Why can using unsigned short be slower than using int?

Tags: c++, types

On [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Programming_Languages/C%2B%2B/Code/Statements/Variables/Type/Data_Types) webpage, the comments on unsigned short state:

> Used to reduce memory usage (although the resulting executable may be
> larger and probably slower as compared to using int

Why is this?

Comment: `int` typically used to be the native CPU word length, and as such it could be quicker to move around in memory and between memory and CPU registers. It's mostly about alignment issues.

Comment: take a look [performance-of-built-in-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069489/performance-of-built-in-types-char-vs-short-vs-int-vs-float-vs-double)

Comment: It is, at best, overly broad statement, and you probably should not rely on that source for good information. I doubt there is a good basis for its claim of “probably” slower. Similarly, its claim that `float` is “Used to reduce memory usage when the values used do not vary widely” is suspect (`float` does have a narrower range, but it also has coarser precision). And for `double`, it says “Represents the "normal" size of data the processor deals with; this is the floating-point data-type used normally,” which is without basis. (The name “double” hints it was twice the size of the default.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks, I probably should have checked with more sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the wording *"probably slower"* is too hard.

A theoretical fact is:

Calculations are done with at least `int` size, e.g.

```
short a = 5;
short b = 10;
short c = a + b;
```

This code snippet contains 3 implicit conversions. `a` and `b` are converted to `int` and added. The result is converted back from `int` to `short`. You can't avoid it. Arithmetic in C++ uses at least `int` size. It's called integer promotion.

In practice most conversions will be avoided by the compiler. And the optimizer will also remove many conversions.

Comment: But all those conversions are hypothetical. The result must match what would be computed _as if_ those conversions had been made. In practice they can often be omitted entirely, depending on the CPU architecture.

Comment: The compiler does any conversion in this process?

Comment: @IssamTP What is _"the compiler"_? Which compiler? There are many different compilers and they behave different.

Comment: Agree with @TonyK. Just compare these two functions for adding `short`/`int` arrays: https://godbolt.org/z/KnxEJA. Clearly, GCC targeting AVX2 uses packed 16-bit addition for `short` (`vpaddw` instruction), so there is no conversion to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

Oftentimes, the short will be modified into an int when passed into a function. This will require some additional generated code to do that. So even if you define a short, the function will take it as an int.

Comment: Or, even to `long`, if arguments are passed in 64-bit registers: https://godbolt.org/z/FFd4-7.